# How can I use sort by custom date in file?

Tags: bash, sorting

I have log file like this:

```
Fri Jan 30 13:52:57 2015 1 10.1.1.1 0 /home/test1/MAIL_201401301353.201501301352.19721.sqlLdr b _ i r test1 ftp 0 * c
Fri Jan 30 13:52:58 2015 1 10.1.1.1 0 /home/test2/MAIL_201401301354.201501301352.12848.sqlLdr b _ i r test2 ftp 0 * c
Fri Jan 30 13:53:26 2015 1 10.1.1.1 0 /home/test3/MAIL_201401301352.201501301353.17772.sqlLdr b _ i r test3 ftp 0 * c
```

I need to sort by date value. Date value is first 2014....

I can find date value like this:

```
echo $log | awk '{print $9}' | grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d{9}' | head -n 1
```

How can I sort by this date value(new to old)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort this file you can use:

```
sort -t_ -nk2,2 file
Fri Jan 30 13:53:26 2015 1 10.1.1.1 0 /home/test3/MAIL_201401301352.201501301353.17772.sqlLdr b _ i r test3 ftp 0 * c
Fri Jan 30 13:52:57 2015 1 10.1.1.1 0 /home/test1/MAIL_201401301353.201501301352.19721.sqlLdr b _ i r test1 ftp 0 * c
Fri Jan 30 13:52:58 2015 1 10.1.1.1 0 /home/test2/MAIL_201401301354.201501301352.12848.sqlLdr b _ i r test2 ftp 0 * c
```

**Details:**

```
-n      # numerical sort
-t      # set field separator as _
-k2,2   # sort on 2nd field
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work for me. One more question, if line have two more _ character like this: `XXX_YYY_MAIL_201...` how can I do? Because I can use -t for just one character.

Comment: In that case `sort -t/ -k4,4 file` will be better `sort` command.

Comment: `sed -e 's/MAIL_2/@2/'  file | sort -t@ ... | sed -e 's/@/MAIL_/' ` (untested)